# Calc CRC8 for objective c

Tags: objective-c, checksum, crc

I need the method to check sum CRC8.
I found this code, but it's not working:

```
 - (int)crc8Checksum:(NSString*)dataFrame{

     char j;
     int crc8 = 0;
     int x = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < [dataFrame length]; i++){
         x = [dataFrame characterAtIndex:i];

         for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
             j = 1 & (x ^ crc8);
             crc8 = floor0(crc8 / 2) & 0xFF;
             x = floor0(x / 2) & 0xFF;
             if (j != 0 ){
                 crc8 = crc8 ^ 0x8C;
             }
         }
     }
     return crc8;
 }
```

Help me please!

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Also, are you getting any errors? Or is the output not what you expect?

Comment: Xcode say "floor0" is old C method.

Comment: That's a somewhat odd implementation of crc (it takes NSString and works on characters, which introduces lots of ways to go wrong). Try this one: https://github.com/cconway/RFduinoUBP/blob/master/iOS/UBP-Demo/UBP-Demo/NSData%2BCRC8.m

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "it's not working"? There are 14 different CRC-8 definitions in [this catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.8), and probably many more out there in the wild. Do you have some CRC values you are comparing to? Is there documentation on what CRC you actually need? What are your test messages and corresponding expected CRCs?

You can't just pick some random CRC-8 code and expect it to do what you need.

That particular code computes a CRC-8/MAXIM in the linked catalog. However it is truly awful code. With unnecessary divides and floors. Here is a better, simpler, faster inner loop:

```
    crc8 ^= x;
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        crc8 = crc8 & 1 ? (crc8 >> 1) ^ 0x8c : crc8 >> 1;
```

You can get it faster still with tables and algorithms that compute the CRC a byte at a time or a machine word at a time.

The `x` in the code has its own problems, since an NSString can be a string of unicode characters, so `characterAtIndex` may not return a byte, and `length` may not return the number of bytes. You need a way to get the message as a series of bytes.